# Nevigating One ViewController to another on Spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit project with two view controllers. One is default GameViewController and another I added a TableViewController.
I want to switch between GameViewController to TableViewController.It did not switch the view controller.

In GameScene.m

```
GameViewController *vc =(GameViewController*)self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc moveToFriendsViewController];
    NSLog(@"vc called from gamescene");
```

In GameViewController.h

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)moveToFriendsViewController;

@end

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController<ViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

In GameViewController.m

```
-(void)moveToFriendsViewController{
   FriendsTableViewController *vc =[[FriendsTableViewController alloc] init];

// do any setup you need for myNewVC

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
NSLog(@"vc called from viewcontroller");

}
```

Comment: You're probably better off just using a scrolling node as your table.

Comment: @sangony how to do that, can you please explain little more?

Comment: Added some code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample project for you to understand what I meant by using a scrolling node. It is very generic in nature and you can tweak, modify and add your own values, code, etc...

I store the user's y position in the touchesBegan method. I then check for any changes in y during the touchesMoved method and move the menuNode accordingly. However, there are other ways of doing this. You could for example just add a "up" and "down" button and move the menu based on which one is touched. Different approach but same result.

To see if a menu item was selected, I compare the user's y position touch from the touchesBegan method to the y position in the touchesEnded method. If there is no change, the user did not swipe up or down and I NSLog the selected node. You can add a tolerance of a couple points here in case the user moves the touch just a little bit.

Again, it's generic code and there are many ways to do what you want but this should give you a couple of ideas to work with.

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene {
    // declare ivars
    SKSpriteNode *menuNode;
    float yTouch;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    // add menu background
    menuNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor darkGrayColor] size:CGSizeMake(200, 1000)];
    menuNode.name = @"menuNode";
    menuNode.position = CGPointMake(100, 800);
    menuNode.zPosition = 10;
    [self addChild:menuNode];

    float yPos = -450;

    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        SKLabelNode *menuItem = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"HelveticaNeue"];
        menuItem.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"menuItem-%i",i];
        menuItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"menuItem-%i",i];
        menuItem.fontSize = 20;
        menuItem.fontColor = [SKColor redColor];
        menuItem.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
        menuItem.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
        menuItem.position = CGPointMake(0, yPos);
        menuItem.zPosition = 25;
        [menuNode addChild:menuItem];

        yPos += 40;
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        // get starting y position of touch
        yTouch = touchLocation.y;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        // check for changes in touched y position and menuNode limits
        if((touchLocation.y > yTouch) && (menuNode.position.y < 800)) {
            menuNode.position = CGPointMake(menuNode.position.x, menuNode.position.y+15);
        }
        if((touchLocation.y < yTouch) && (menuNode.position.y > 200))   {
            menuNode.position = CGPointMake(menuNode.position.x, menuNode.position.y-15);
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    // if current touch position y is same as when touches began
    if(touchLocation.y == yTouch) {
        NSLog(@"%@",node);
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xibs, your method should work, but in Storyboard the below method will work fine.

```
 -(void)moveToFriendsViewController{
       FriendsTableViewController *vc =[[FriendsTableViewController alloc] init];

     UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
            UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FriendsTableViewController"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"vc called from viewcontroller");

    }
```

Comment: if you are using tableview then you should use tableviewdidselectforRowatIndexpath method, 
Please reply

Comment: error 1: redefine vc then I remove UIStoryboard * error 2: reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x17005a220>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier

Comment: dear you have to create an instance of that view controller that is to be called. Like you say you have a view controller named "MySecondViewController" you have you create an instance like MySecondSecondViewController* second
And second thing you have to link your specific class and set StoryBoardID else it won't work out

Comment: when I click friend button it shows FriendViewController but when I comeback to GameViewController then it do not do anything?

Comment: since i am using push ,
it should go to previous screen
or you can popviewcontroller in you back button,

Comment: embed the main controller(Game controller)  in navigationcontroller and set it to initial controller i.e: navigation controller

Comment: or if using natively gaming point of view
read this one
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW10